# How was Jupiter formed

Tags: jupiter, planetary-formation

Two days ago I went to a mathematics conference where there was a paper presented on Jupiter's formation via the disk-instability model.

I know that there are two different theories for the formation of the planets. One of them is the **Core accretion** model and the other one is the **disk-instability** model. I also tried to read this paper on planetary formation in which they said 161 planets were put on to test. 90% followed Core accretion model and rest of them followed the later model. Did not say anything explicit about Jupiter.

Jupiter is too close to the Sun to follow the Disk-Instability model (I am not sure completely).

Now I want to know which model Jupiter follows for its formation.
(I asked this question on physics stack-exchange too but unfortunately there were no answers)

Comment: Currently nobody knows. There are two possible options being pursued - core accretion and disk instability...

Comment: But that *is* the answer to the question you have asked.

Answer (score 1):

Maxwell's Smith Prize Essay on the formation of the Rings of Saturn is relevant. Using structural stability as his criterion, he deduced that the 'rings' could only consist of a single almost infinite mass of very small particulates each orbiting in accord with Newtonian dynamics--the correct result as verified by NASA/ Cassini.
 Applying the same approach to a forming  solar system this analysis shows that rings of particulates are a structurally stable attractor for the dynamics, provided the central star is much larger than the mean particulate size.
I am now  well outside my comfort zone so will leave further inferences to others :).
[Maxwell's essay on rings of saturn](http://www.clerkmaxwellfoundation.org/Saturn-s_Rings.pdf)

Comment: How does this relate to the formation of Jupiter?

Comment: improved my answer on the basis of a kind comment